# How can I see if staff has a certificate? (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have three tables in SQLite3:

certificates

```
cert_id
caption
```

staff

```
staff_id
name
cc_id
```

rel__staff_certificate

```
relation_id
staff_id
cert_id
```

ccdata

```
cc_id 
cc_name
```

How should I make a SQL that will see if staff has a relation between the staff and the certificate?

Comment: Any attempts on your side?

Comment: Are you just looking for the `JOIN` keyword?

Comment: I count *three* tables actually ;-)

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear enough, and yes its three tables :D

This is the output that I want to create in HTML table:

Customer center|Cert1|Cert2|Cert3|Staff count
----------------------------------------------
Sweden|20|5|0|40
Norway|5|5|5|15
Denmark|25|10|20|68
------------------
TOTAL|50|20|25|123


The "Cert1|Cert2|Cert3" are stored in table "certificates":

cert_id
caption


The customer centers are stored in table "cc_data":

cc_id
cc_name


Each customer center has staff in it, in table "staff":

staff_id
cc_id (tells what customer center staff is connected to)
name

Continue...

Comment: ...Continue:

A relation is created in table "rel__staff_certificate" for each time a staff member of a customer center has passed a certificate in table "certificates":

relation_id
staff_id
cert_id


Any suggestions? Let me know if this is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out by some help on IRC and reading up on JOIN:

```
SELECT ccdata.cc_name, ccdata.cc_code, rel__staff_certificate.cert_id, rel__staff_certificate.cert_date, staff.cc_id, COUNT(*) AS staffcount_certified FROM staff JOIN rel__staff_certificate ON staff.staff_id = rel__staff_certificate.staff_id JOIN ccdata ON staff.cc_id = ccdata.cc_id WHERE staff.date_invalid = '' AND rel__staff_certificate.cert_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' GROUP BY ccdata.cc_name, rel__staff_certificate.cert_id, staff.cc_id, ccdata.cc_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are looking for - a list of staff with specific certificates, a list of staffs with any certificates, or a list of each staff member and each certificate they have.

```
SELECT name, certificate FROM staff 

INNER JOIN 

rel__staff_certificate ON staff.staff_id = rel__staff_certificate.staff_id 

INNER JOIN 

certificates ON rel__staff_certificate.cert_id = certificates.cert_id
```

This will show you a list of each staff and certificate combination. I suggest you look at the `JOIN` keyword and do some research of your own. I find SQLZoo to be a good resource for learning.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a list like this actually:

Image: http://i.imgur.com/M7qXyHO.png

Comment: Okay. Where is the table that tracks the customer service centre?

Comment: It is stored in table "staff" under "cc_id". "cc_id" represents the ID number of the customer center stored in table "ccdata". See images:

http://imgur.com/pyfqGXn,UAdhr87#0